# Process bulk XLS in PHP

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to process more than 1,00,000 XLS rows with PHP script (using PHPEXCEL library http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/107442) and insert into MYSQL but every time it gives me timeout. So I have changed the memory limits, execution limit and post size limit

```
set_time_limit(1800);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '512M');
ini_set('post_max_size','250M');
```

Timeout problem was sorted but now I am getting server reset while loading of EXCEL file with PHPEXCEL library.

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() );
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

**I am getting server reset here.**

```
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
            ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX  Document")
            ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX  Document")
            ->setDescription(" Document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
            ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")->setCategory("php result file");
$this->dump($objPHPExcel);
// to iterate sheets
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
    // to iterate rows
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
    {
       $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
       $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
       // to iterate cells
       foreach ($cellIterator as $cell => $val) {
```

Unfortunately never got any script or tutorial to handle bulk data parsing in php.

Please help

Comment: If you're working with bulk data like this, then you really should be doing it as a background task - not via a web script

Comment: are you inserting records at once or one by one ?

Comment: Rather than iterating through every cell in the row, why not use the rangeToArray() method to retrieve all the cell data for each row in a single call rather than in a loop

Comment: `$this->dump($objPHPExcel);` isn't a good idea either, dumping the details of the entire workbook will be a big overhead

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for reply.You are right about using $this->dump($objPHPExcel) in wrong way.I will change that. My main problem is with $objReader->load($inputFileName). It couldn't go further in process.FYI it iterates upto 10,000 XLS rows but not more than that.

Comment: Processing a file with a complex file structure will always be slow; which is why I'd recommend doing it as a back-end process when you can adjust the script timeout limit without leaving a user wondering what is going on; but processing a row at a time via rangeToArray() will be faster to execute than iterating through every cell in the row

Comment: Yes it is. So that's why I have also tried it with shell command but everytime it returns me 'KILLED'. It couldn't reach to the row iterator code.All code halts in LOAD() method of library.Please help me.

Comment: What your data looks like in Excel file? What kind of processing are you trying to do? Can you save your file as CSV?

Comment: @peterm I have 9-10 cells in my Excel file. I am tying to process all rows in throw into SQL DB. Unfortunately no successes with CSV.

Comment: What do you mean by *...Unfortunately no successes with CSV...*? If it's just rows of plain data, meaning no complex structure, fixed number of columns, no complex processing needed to exrtact data from your Excel file then you most likely can save it as CSV file and use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load your data to your database. It is BTW the fastest method of loading data from file for MySql.

Comment: I mean to say that I have also tried with CSV parsing but couldn't proceed. I don't have any complex structure in rows. Its plain data but the thing is that I need to alter the data before the insertion in DB.

Comment: @amrKamboj If you still need help with your question consider to post sample file data (a few relevant lines), target table schema, and explanation what alterations you want to be done

Comment: @peterm I still need help.Now I don't need alteration.But need to check existing record in DB.This is the sample [XLS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqqvnurlhcg65oz/XLS.xls). I am trying to parse all XLS rows and then match it with DB and get the no. of duplicate rows and rows to add. But not succeed with upto 1 lac rows. I have also tried with [CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kuvov5j7o58n1m/CSV.csv) with (;) delimiter, but there is a long string in CSV with ',' and '\r\n' and everytime script generates a row for \r\n. CSV is taking too less time to process but all wrong thing is '\r\n'.